# Vertx doesnt pickup extern conf file

Tags: java, guice, vert.x

I am using vertx and guice this way:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {


        final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(StarterVerticle.class);
        ClusterManager mgr = new HazelcastClusterManager();
        VertxOptions options = new VertxOptions().setClusterManager(mgr);
        Vertx.clusteredVertx(options, res -> {
            DeploymentOptions deploymentOptions = new DeploymentOptions().setConfig(config);

            if (res.succeeded()) {
                Vertx vertx = res.result();
                //  Injector injector = Guice.createInjector(new AppInjector(vertx));
                Injector injector = Guice.createInjector(new AppInjector(vertx,deploymentOptions));
                vertx.deployVerticle(injector.getInstance(VertxHttpServerVerticle.class), deploymentOptions);
                vertx.deployVerticle(injector.getInstance(Verticle1.class), deploymentOptions);
                vertx.deployVerticle(injector.getInstance(Verticle2.class), deploymentOptions);
                logger.info("World Map Service module deployed on vertx!");
            } else {
                logger.error("Error initiating Vertx cluster");
            }
        });
    }
```

I dropped `my-app.json` at my main project dir: `my-app-conf.json`

```
{
  "http.port" : 8082
}
```

VertxHttpServerVerticle:

```
public class VertxHttpServerVerticle extends AbstractVerticle {


    @Override
    public void start(Future<Void> fut) {

 ....
                .createHttpServer()
                .requestHandler(router::accept)
                .listen(
                        // Retrieve the port from the configuration,
                        // default to 8090.
                        config().getString("http.port", "8090"),
```

http.port won't be collected.
I executed the jar this way:

```
 java -jar web/build/libs/com.my-app-all.jar -conf wm-conf.json
```

I still get for `config().getString("http.port")` null

Any idea what am I missing?

Answer (score 3):

If you want pass configuration via -conf param your initial Class should extend `AbstractVerticle`.

If you deploy Verticle via `vertx.deployVerticle()` you should pass `http.port` manualy into `config` and then pass such object to `DeploymentOptions` instance.

You can read more about Verticle deployments in [vert.x documenation](http://vertx.io/docs/vertx-core/java/).

Comment: But you start you application via ```public static void main``` method. Your code should looks like in this example: https://github.com/vert-x3/vertx-examples/tree/master/maven-verticles/maven-verticle

Comment: coz I am using embedded mode.

Answer (score 0):

Your jar tries to load the config from the web/build/libs dir, while the file actually is located in your project root. Try using relative paths "../../../wm-conf.json" or just move the conf file asside the jar.

Comment: the.jar indeed under web.../libs dir but the conf file at the root level. still config isnt populated.